# Customer and Partner community access to same user

Tags: community, customer-community, partner-communities

Can I have the same contact/user to have access to both customer and partner community? Can the user login to both communities with same credentials?

Comment: Yes you can assign the same profile to different communities and the user will be able to login using the same credentials.  Communities do not have hardcoded restrictions against specific community license types.

Comment: I want to only give access to both communities to only certain users. I went the permission set route to give access to partner community for customer community user. But the permission set does not allow me to grant read/edit access to leads object